# problem to find if an element repeating 2 times print those numbers i didn't get any output

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, arraylist

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, j, count, n, a[100], c[100], k = 0;

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter elements: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        count = 1;

        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                count++;
                a[j] = -1;
            }
        }

        if (count == 2 && a[i] != -1) {
            c[i] = a[i];
            k++;
        }
    }

    printf("Duplicate elements with their occurrences:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

problem to find if an element repeating 2 times print those numbers
i didn't get any output
array problem printing elements those are repeating 2 times

Comment: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the control flow and the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

`c[i] = a[i];` is placing elements in `c` at the same indices where they are found in `a`.

Instead, you want to use the current value of `k` to append new values to `c`:

```
if (count == 2 && a[i] != -1) {
    c[k++] = a[i];
}
```

Additionally, `count == 2` should be `count > 1` to check for multiple duplicates, rather than a single duplicate.

---

Other things to do include:

- Check that `scanf` returns the expected number of successful *conversions*, and reject invalid values (oversized array, sentinel value).
- Skip sentinel values (`-1`) immediately.
- Use `size_t` instead of `int` for array indices.
- Zero-initializing arrays reduces noise when [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/2505965).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(void)
{
    size_t n;
    int a[MAX] = { 0 };
    int c[MAX] = { 0 };

    printf("Enter size of array: ");
    if (1 != scanf("%zu", &n) || n > MAX) {
        fputs("Invalid size.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter elements: ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (1 != scanf("%d", &a[i]) || -1 == a[i]) {
            fputs("Invalid value.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    size_t k = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        unsigned count = 1;

        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (-1 == a[i])
                continue;

            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                a[j] = -1;
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 1)
            c[k++] = a[i];
    }

    printf("Duplicate elements:\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        printf("%d ", c[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
Enter size of array: 5
Enter elements: 1 2 3 3 2
Duplicate elements:
2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly I would suggest giving each of your variables a meaningful name, 'a'/'k' doesn't provide any information about the purpose of the variable and creates confusion, and makes it harder for other people to read your code properly. 'array1' or 'array1Counter' would be much clearer for example. just a friendly tip(;

second, the problem may lie in the condition of your second 'if'. You require the 'count' variable to be equal to 2 even though if there are 3 of the same value in the array your program wouldn't work, try making the 'count' variable a bool instead of an integer, and changing its value to true once you find the same value, that way you could have a hundred of the same number in the array and it would still work.

other than that your code seems just fine so if my suggestion doesn't work, if I were you, I would try rewriting it in small steps, making sure each step works, and then you'll find exactly where the problem lies. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Oka has [identified the issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77895591/15261315) with your code and made several useful suggestions for improvements.

However, algorithmically, your solution can be substantially better. Right now it has a loop within a loop which gives it a runtime complexity of O(n^2). This scales very poorly. If you sort the numbers first, and a good sort has a runtime complexity of O(n * log n), then detecting duplicates is a linear or O(n) operation.

For sorting, [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) provides an easy solution, and the linked page even provides sorting ints as an example.